# Excel VBA UserForm - Userform not closing when textbox is empty

Tags: excel, textbox, userform

I am new to creating userforms in excel and only started picking excel vba not long ago! I am hoping that I can find a solution to my problem here. Have been scratching my head over this.

I have a userform that have the following:

1. Textbox1 which will populate if Column Y have errors
2. A multipage where users will fill up according to the information given in textbox1.

Right now what works is that textbox1 will populate when Column Y have errors, but when there is no errors in Column Y, I want it to popup a message box that says "no errors found!" and after click "ok", the code will stop and the userform will automatically close.

Below is my code for the Add button, where after clicking "Add", textbox1 will be populated with the next cell with error and my code when the userform is initialized.

```
Private Sub PFBtnAdd_Click()

Dim oCtl As MSForms.Control
Dim TStr As String

    Dim iPg As Integer
    iPg = Me.MultiPage1.Value
    For Each oCtl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(iPg).Controls
        Select Case TypeName(oCtl)
        Case "TextBox"
            If oCtl.Value = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "All fields are mandatory. Please check the fields."
                oCtl.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case Else:
        End Select
        Next oCtl

Dim ctyRng As Range
Dim InpRange As Range
Dim wsRng As Range
Dim wsn As String

Set ctyRng = Worksheets("ITS Countries & PFG").Range("A2:B305")
Set InpRange = Worksheets("AddNew").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

'Add New details
InpRange.Offset(, 4).Value = PFCarrCB.Value

If PFEntST.Value Then
InpRange.Value = "2"
wsn = "2." & PFCarrCB.Value
ElseIf PFEntOPT.Value Then
InpRange.Value = "1"
wsn = "1." & PFCarrCB.Value
End If

On Error Resume Next
If Worksheets(wsn).FilterMode Then Worksheets(wsn).ShowAllData

InpRange.Offset(, 5).Value = PFPFGCB.Value
InpRange.Offset(, 7).Value = UCase(PFSCTB.Value)
InpRange.Offset(, 8).Value = CDate(PFDateTB.Value)
InpRange.Offset(, 10).Value = "Y"
InpRange.Offset(, 11).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PFCtyCB.Value, ctyRng, 2, False)
InpRange.Offset(, 13).Value = "N"

Set wsRng = Worksheets(wsn).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

On Error Resume Next
wsRng.Value = PFCarrCB.Value
wsRng.Offset(, 3).Value = PFPFGCB.Value
On Error Resume Next
If PFICInv.Value Then
InpRange.Offset(, 6).Value = UCase(PFICInv.Caption)
wsRng.Offset(, 4).Value = UCase(PFICInv.Caption)
ElseIf PFICStmt.Value Then
InpRange.Offset(, 6).Value = UCase(PFICStmt.Caption)
wsRng.Offset(, 4).Value = UCase(PFICStmt.Caption)
End If
On Error Resume Next
wsRng.Offset(, 5).Value = UCase(PFSCTB.Value)
wsRng.Offset(, 1).Value = PFISCTB.Value
wsRng.Offset(, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PFCtyCB.Value, ctyRng, 2, False)

PFPFGCB.Value = ""
PFISCTB.Value = ""

UserForm_Initialize
PFCtyCB.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
'find the last row number of a range using Find Function
  LastRow = mysheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsError(Cells(i, 25).Value) Then
    Me.SCTB.Value = mysheet.Cells(i, 35).Value & " | " & mysheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & " | US$ " & mysheet.Cells(i, 23).Value
    End If
Next i

PFDateTB.Text = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "Short Date")
PFCarrCB.Value = Range("B2").Value
SCCarrCB.Value = Range("B2").Value

If Range("A2").Value = 2 Then
PFEntST.Value = True
SCEntST.Value = True
ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 1 Then
PFEntOPT.Value = True
SCEntOPT.Value = True
End If

If Range("E2").Value = "IC INVOICE" Then
PFICInv.Value = True
SCICInv.Value = True
ElseIf Range("E2").Value = "IC STMNT" Then
PFICStmt.Value = True
SCICStmt.Value = True
End If

End Sub
```

I have attached an image of how the userform looks like. The line "155 | 0.04 | US$ 28176.94" is textbox1.

Below are codes I have found and I tried, it works as it populates textbox1, but after clicking 'Add' for the last cell with error, userform is still active and textbox1 is still populated with the last cell (which doesn't have error anymore). Upon clicking 'Add', it should tell me that there are no more errors found and proceed to close the Userform.

If I reopen the userform and there is no more error in Column Y, a msgbox should pop up to inform me that there are no more errors found and after clicking on "ok", the userform should not pop up again.

```
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
'find the last row number of a range using Find Function
  LastRow = mysheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsError(Cells(i, 25).Value) Then
    Me.SCTB.Value = mysheet.Cells(i, 35).Value & " | " & mysheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & " | US$ " & mysheet.Cells(i, 23).Value
    End If
Next i
```

I have assigned the below macro to a shape (used as a button) on my sheet

```
Sub OpenUFPFG()
   With UFAdd
        .Width = 313.5
        .Height = 300
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
    UFAdd.MultiPage1.Value = 1
    UFAdd.PFCtyCB.SetFocus
End Sub
```